# String format positive and negative values and conditional color formatting XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am looking for a simple way to format my result using the following criteria: If positive, add a plus and show it green, if it's negative add a minus and show it red.

I am half way there, I just don't know what's the easiest way to get the color formatting. Is there a way without using a value converter?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActualValue, StringFormat='({0:+0.0;-0.0})'}"></TextBlock>
```

What's the smartest way to go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without a converter. Here's one that can do the job for number types (except for `char`):

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(byte), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(long), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(float), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(uint), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(short), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(sbyte), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(ushort), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(ulong), typeof(Brush))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(decimal), typeof(Brush))]
public class SignToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Brush DefaultNegativeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private static readonly Brush DefaultPositiveBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    private static readonly Brush DefaultZeroBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

    static SignToBrushConverter()
    {
        DefaultNegativeBrush.Freeze();
        DefaultPositiveBrush.Freeze();
        DefaultZeroBrush.Freeze();
    }

    public Brush NegativeBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush PositiveBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush ZeroBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!IsSupportedType(value)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        double doubleValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

        if (doubleValue < 0d) return NegativeBrush ?? DefaultNegativeBrush;
        if (doubleValue > 0d) return PositiveBrush ?? DefaultPositiveBrush;

        return ZeroBrush ?? DefaultZeroBrush;
    }

    private static bool IsSupportedType(object value)
    {
        return value is int || value is double || value is byte || value is long ||
               value is float || value is uint || value is short || value is sbyte || 
               value is ushort || value is ulong || value is decimal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<local:SignToBrushConverter x:Key="SignToBrushConverter" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActualValue, StringFormat='({0:+0.0;-0.0})'}" 
           Foreground="{Binding ActualValue, Converter={StaticResource SignToBrushConverter}}" />
```

Or if you want to override the default colors:

```
<local:SignToBrushConverter x:Key="SignToBrushConverter" NegativeBrush="Purple" PositiveBrush="DodgerBlue" ZeroBrush="Chocolate" />
```

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs, this solved my issue. It works flawlessly. Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to use **data triggers**, because in general cases foreground and string format might be not only properties to be changed. And in most cases data triggers are used to change **DataTemplate** of controls.

Here is code example for your case:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:PositiveConverter x:Key="PositiveConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="NumericTextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PositiveConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat='({0:+0.0})'}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PositiveConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding StringFormat='({0:-0.0})'}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Positive}" Style="{StaticResource NumericTextBlock}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Negative}" Style="{StaticResource NumericTextBlock}"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

**And code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Positive = 4;
        Negative = -7;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public double Positive { get; set; }
    public double Negative { get; set; }
}
```

**And finally converter class:**

```
public class PositiveConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var number = 0.0;
        var isNumber = double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out number);

        return isNumber && number >= 0.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very well explained example. I got in partially working. It turns red or green based on the value but the string format doesn't seem to apply. (e.g.: instead of getting +15.72, the result is 15.7272727) What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work all the way?